# SQL Server Polybase: 110064;Windows authentication failed

Tags: sql-server, polybase

I faced a problem with Polybase.
When I try to create external file format, e.g.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT [TestFileFormat] WITH (FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT, FORMAT_OPTIONS (FIELD_TERMINATOR = N'!', USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = True))
```

I get the error:

Msg 110064, Level 16, State 62, Line 5
110064;Windows authentication failed. Possible network configuration issue. Please contact your system administrator.

Can somebody say, where is a problem?

Comment: Do other operations work, or is it just the external file formats? I don't know Polybase but I'd guess either the user you're logged into SQL Server as or the user that SQL Server is running as doesn't have permissions on one of the external data warehouse systems.

Comment: I'm able to create external data source without problems. A trouble with external file format only.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem to.

Msg 110064, Level 16, State 62, Line 49 110064;Windows authentication failed. Possible network configuration issue. Please contact your system administrator.

I think it works on RTM and stop working after applying CU.

Comment: So you're saying a workaround is to roll back the CU (= Cumulative Update?). Is that a SQL Server update or a Windows update? Which version of SQL Server are you talking about?